# Suppose that $F,G \in NBV$ and $-\infty <a<b< \infty$, how show that

Tags: measure-theory, functions

Suppose that $F,G \in NBV$ and $-\infty <a<b< \infty$, how show that

$\displaystyle\int_{[a,b]} \dfrac{F(x)+F(x-)}{2}dG(x) + \displaystyle\int_{[a,b]} \dfrac{G(x)+G(x-)}{2}dF(x) = F(b)G(b)-F(a-)G(a-)$

where $F(a-)=\lim_{x \to a^-} F(x) $.

This exercise is from Folland Real analysis. The author suggests that he imitate the proof of Theorem 3.36, but I am not able to use the same lines. Can someone give a tip?

Comment: Did you try approximating with functions in $C^1$ ?

Comment: I think this does not help. There probably must be a trick to use along with the fubini's theorem

Comment: Fubini is obtained from approximating with functions in $C^0_c$. What fails when approximating with functions in $C^1$ ?